# The application is not stopped after selenium close and quit

Tags: java, selenium

I have a simple web-scraping application.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        File file = new File("C:/Users/Евгений/Desktop/chromedriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/shop/fresh-food/all");
        String imageUrl = driver.findElement(By.className("product-image__container"))
                .findElement(By.className("product-image")).getAttribute("src");
        System.out.println(imageUrl);
        driver.close();
        System.err.println("closed");

    }
```

The problem is after the code is done the application is not stopped. What could be the problem and the proper way to end the selenium application?

Comment: What do you mean when say _app is not stopped_? How do you execute it and what exactly are you observing?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ idea ultimate and application just keeps running without returning finish code until I stop it

Comment: I've thought that there might be a problem in my code but I guess the problem is that my computer is too slow.

Comment: try to run the code from cmd. This will give you a clue about if the issue is with IDE.

Comment: Rolled back the edit. Please do not edit your question in a way that invalidates existing answers. Just post a new question, perfectly fine. You can of course also link to this thread for context then. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `driver.close()` to `driver.quit()`. This will destroy the driver and release resources unlike `close()` which closes the current window.

So the normal practice would be using the construction like this:

```java
try {
    // your code here
}finally {
    if (driver != null) {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also make sure to quit in all cases, including exceptions. So `try-finally` quit. (If it is implementing `AutoClosable`, prefer try-with-resources).